# Image processing: interpolation using intensity values of pixels in the input image

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, bicubic

When we do image interpolation, I think we will use intensity values of pixels in the input image.

(A)
I am reading the code of cubic interpolation from [GPU Gems Chapter 24. High-Quality Filtering](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_ch24.html). Here is a snippet of their code:

Example 24-9. Filtering Four Texel Rows, Then Filtering the Results as a Column

```
float4 texRECT_bicubic(uniform 
   samplerRECT tex,
                       uniform 
   samplerRECT kernelTex,
                       float2 t)
{
  float2 f = frac(t);  // we want the sub-texel portion

   float4 t0 = cubicFilter(kernelTex, f.x,
                          texRECT(tex, t + float2(-1, -1)),
                          texRECT(tex, t + float2(0, -1)),
                          texRECT(tex, t + float2(1, -1)),
                          texRECT(tex, t + float2(2, -1)));
```

Since they get the sub-texel protion from frac(t), "t" is not exactly on pixel positions of the input image.
Then how come "t" is directly used to sample intensity values from the original images, like in "texRECT(tex, t + float2(-1, -1))"?

Personally, I think we should use

```
t - frac(t)
```

(B)
Same in an example from "[Zoom An Image With Different Interpolation Types](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236394/Bi-Cubic-and-Bi-Linear-Interpolation-with-GLSL#GLSLBiCubic)"

Their snippet of "GLSL shader code for Bi-Cubic Interpolation" is:

```
float a = fract( TexCoord.x * fWidth ); // get the decimal part
float b = fract( TexCoord.y * fHeight ); // get the decimal part

for( int m = -1; m <=2; m++ )
{
    for( int n =-1; n<= 2; n++)
    {
        vec4 vecData = texture2D(textureSampler, 
                           TexCoord + vec2(texelSizeX * float( m ), 
                texelSizeY * float( n )));
```

I think we should use:

```
TexCoord - vec2(a,b)
```

then use offset of m and n

(C) Now I am confused. I think we will use intensity values of "exact" pixels in the input image.
Which way should we use?

Comment: Interpolation is about using exact pixel values to estimate the value of a pixel that isn't on an exact pixel boundary. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: By "exact pixel values", you meant "exact pixel values on the original input image", right? So I think their code seems not to follow the rule....

Comment: I suspect `texRect` truncates the coordinates to integers to get the exact pixel value. I don't know enough about it to say for sure though.

Comment: it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.